# Programmatically create a list of lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to create a list of lists by reading a file of data and I can't get it to work.

To show what I'm trying to do I have the following hard-coded list of lists that works for my purpose.  Each list contains a room name, followed by an x and y coordinate.  This is for a robot navigation program.

Here's the hard-coded listing that works.

```
nav_Array =[["studio",145.0,155.0],["kitchen",245.0,400.0]]
print (nav_Array[0])
print (nav_Array[1])
print ("\n")
print (nav_Array[0][0])
print (nav_Array[0][1])
print (nav_Array[0][2])
print ("\n")    
print (nav_Array[1][0])
print (nav_Array[1][1])
print (nav_Array[1][2])
```

Here's the printed output I expected and got:

```
['studio', 145.0, 155.0]
['kitchen', 245.0, 400.0]

studio
145.0
155.0

kitchen
245.0
400.0
```

Now for my problem.

I have the following text file: I can modify the format of this file if need be, but I'd like to keep each entry on a new line for ease of maintenance.  This is a very short excerpt of this file.  The actual file is going to have many more lists.  Each line being a list.  By the way I've tried adding brackets and that doesn't help as you'll see further down:

```
studio,145.0,155.5
kitchen,245.0,400.0
```

So the problem is that I want to read this file into a list of lists like I had manually typed in as nav_Array in the previous example.

Here's what I tried.

First Attempt:

```
    with open(file_path) as myfile: 
        for line in myfile:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print (line)
            nav_Array.append(line)
        myfile.close()
    print "\n"
    print "print nav_Array: ", nav_Array

    print "\n"
    print (nav_Array[0][0])
    print (nav_Array[0][1])
    print (nav_Array[0][2])
    print "\n"
    print (nav_Array[1][0])
    print (nav_Array[1][1])
    print (nav_Array[1][2])
```

The result is the following which is not what I want:

```
studio,145.0,155.5
kitchen,245.0,400.0

print nav_Array:  ['studio,145.0,155.5', 'kitchen,245.0,400.0']

s
t
u

k
i
t
```

That's not creating a list of lists.

So then I tried adding brackets to the original file data like so:

```
[studio,145.0,155.5]
[kitchen,245.0,400.0]
```

Then running the same program as above I get the following output which is better, but still not a list of lists.  The following is the output:

```
[studio,145.0,155.5]
[kitchen,245.0,400.0]

print nav_Array:  ['[studio,145.0,155.5]', '[kitchen,245.0,400.0]']

[
s
t


[
k
i
```

For some reason single quotes are being put in by the append function.  And that ruins what I'm trying to do.  If I could get rid of those single quotes I'd be home free.

So then I tried the following to the original file format.  All I did here was trying to add the [] in the append function itself, but this gives me precisely the same result as placing the [] in the data file.

The only line difference here is nav_Array.append("["+line+"]")

```
    with open(file_path) as myfile: 
        for line in myfile:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print (line)
            nav_Array.append("["+line+"]")
        myfile.close()
    print "\n"
    print "print nav_Array: ", nav_Array

    print "\n"
    print (nav_Array[0][0])
    print (nav_Array[0][1])
    print (nav_Array[0][2])
    print "\n"
    print (nav_Array[1][0])
    print (nav_Array[1][1])
    print (nav_Array[1][2])
```

And this gives me the same output I got when I added the square brackets to the data file directly.

```
studio,145.0,155.5
kitchen,245.0,400.0

print nav_Array:  ['[studio,145.0,155.5]', '[kitchen,245.0,400.0]']

[
s
t

[
k
i
```

Again that's not what I need.  I need what I got when I typed in the list of lists by hand in the first example at the top of this post.

Just for the record, I've been trying tons of other things as well.  I've been reading a lot of Stack Overflow posts on how to import lists from files, but I haven't been able to find anything that addresses bringing in an actual list of lists.

I'm almost there!  I just can't get rid of the single quotes that appear to be introduced automatically by the append function.

I'm thinking I could write a program to go through and strip out those single quotes as a last resort.  But surely there's a better way to build a list of lists without having to do that.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If possible, you should switch to Python 3.6+ while you are still learning.  https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 2):

Make use of splitlines and split:

```
s = """
studio,145.0,155.5
kitchen,245.0,400.0
"""

final = [i.split(',') for i in s.splitlines() if i]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['studio', '145.0', '155.5'], ['kitchen', '245.0', '400.0']]
```

**Or for a file**:

> test.txt

```
studio,145.0,155.5
kitchen,245.0,400.0
```

You can use:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    final = [i.split(',') for i in f.read().splitlines() if i]
    print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['studio', '145.0', '155.5'], ['kitchen', '245.0', '400.0']]
```

Comment: I would have never figured out final = [i.split(',') for i in f.read().splitlines() if i], in fact, I don't understand how that's working.  But it does work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) works well with csv files. :)

```
import csv
with open('my.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(reader)
print(a)
```

---

```
>>>
[['studio', '145.0', '155.5'], ['kitchen', '245.0', '400.0']]
>>>
```

Comment: Yep!  That works too.  Thanks!  I knew there had to be easy ways to do this.